# How can we use expression component in mule4

Tags: mule, expression, mule-component, dataweave

Need to know how can we use below expression component in mule 4 using DW or any other

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression to remove ["><![CDATA[payload=payload.replace('[','');]]></expression-component>
```

Input is:

```
[A 01 02 03 04, B 01 02 03 04, C 01 02 03 04]
```

Expected Output is:

```
A 01 02 03 04  
B 01 02 03 04  
C 01 02 03 04
```

Comment: updated answer based on new info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no expression-component in mule 4. Use dataweave transform message component instead.

So with the additional info, i'm guessing you payload is a string(not a java array?)and your ouput is a space delimited csv file. If so you can use regex to remove the surrounding brackets and then split by the comma to get the lines and then split by space to get the fields. You can then merge these together to get the expected output like so:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/csv header=false, separator=" "

---
((payload match(/\[(.*?)\]/))[1]) splitBy  ","
map ((item, index) ->  ( (trim(item) splitBy " " ) 
    map (item, index) -> (index as String): item )reduce ($$ ++ $)

)
```

[image]

Comment: I have added input and output samples. Can you check now please.